# Cannot change Xcode project name - 3 targets - Swift Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 and I'm trying to rename my project. When I do, I always end up with errors.

I have 3 targets. 
"Old Name"
"Old NameTests"
"Old Name Extensions"

How should I proceed to change the names? I've tried to do the normal double click, change name. But I end up with an error.

Comment: Can you post the errors you have ?

Comment: "error: Embedded binary's bundle identifier is not prefixed with the parent app's bundle identifier."

Answer (score 1):

1. In Utility Area , Rename the project under "Identify and Type"
2. Window -> Organizer -> Projects .. Delete the derived data path of the project
3. In Editor Area, Targets -> "ProjectName"Tests .. 
   Testing -> Host Application select your renamed project.

Clean and Run.

Answer (score 0):

With the error message you posted in comments, you have to check that all your product bundle ID are according to libraries bundles.

Check all you infos.plist and update the bundles id prefix to be the same everywhere.

Comment: Now I get
ld: file not found: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NewName-dqnjtjaxiczneefpmeryixckuowp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OldName.app/OldName
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild

Comment: Sorry not seen that it was the derived data. Open your organizer, select your project and clean the derived data. Cleanup again your project and tell me if you still have the error. If not please accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I still have the error. Deleted all connected folders within the Deriveddata.